# I believe this algorithm runs in O(n^3) time. Correct?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

My reasoning: A simple decrement-by-one loop would run in O(n) time. However, this algorithm makes triply nested passes over the parameter n to decrement all three variables to zero. n * n * n = n^3.

```
public static void downByThree (int n) {
   int x = n;
   while (x > 0) {
       int y = n;
       while (y > 0) {
           int z = n;
           while (z > 0) {
               z--;
           }
           y--;
        }
        x--;
     }
   }
```

Comment: It might do if it had any visible side effects. As is, the compiler (or JIT) will most likely eliminate everything.

Comment: That's correct. …**and** @ElliottFrisch is correct, too.

Comment: Good lord, let me fix this.

Comment: This belongs on codereview.SE.

Comment: @rustyx complexity has nothing to do with performance, or observable behaviour.

Comment: @IanMacDonald No, it doesn't. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users .

Comment: @Sneftel okay. Thanks for the link. codereview.SE is apparently too narrowly focused in its goal.

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
int a = n;
while (a > 0) {
    <body>
    a--;
}
```

is an example of implementing the concept of repeated execution using `while` loop, assuming that `<body>` does not modify `a`. In pseudocode this could look like this:

```
REPEAT n TIMES
    <body>
```

Therefore, your code has the following structure in pseudocode:

```
REPEAT n TIMES
    REPEAT n TIMES
        REPEAT n TIMES
            <no-op>
```

While the compiler could potentially figure out that the code is an n<sup>3</sup> repetitions of `<no-op>` and optimize it out, the algorithm has an O(n<sup>3</sup>) structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is in O(n^3), as you mentionned. Your reasoning is correct, you make the Z loop O(n), then y loop O(n^2) and the last O(n^3).

Comment: Thanks, my formatting went haywire. Here is the paste: https://pastebin.com/GhF9mnie

Answer (score 1):

Your believe is 100% correct. Yes, above algorithm runs in O(n^3) time.
Basically, above code is equivalent to:

```
 for(int x = n; x>0 ; --x){
    for(int y = n; y>0 ; --y){
        for(int z = n; z>0 ; --z){

        }
     }
  }
```

As we can see that there are 3 nested for loops having exactly **n** length, we can conclude time complexity as O(n^3).
More explicitly, ***z*** variable changes **n** times [ O(n) ] for every **n** different ***y*** variables [ O(n*n) ] and this phenomenon happens **n** times for every ***x*** variables. Therefore, overall time complexity will be **O(n^3)**.